# What is Sql query to know data base already exists or not in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can any one tell me the query to know data base name already exists or not in mysq.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to create a database only if i doesnt exist? here is how

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name
```

[Read More](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Temp` use your DB name.

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'Temp'), 'Yes','No')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use mysql;

count * from db where db="your_db_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA to know if the database exists or not. Read more here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html